# Scala get next index in the list from current item

Tags: scala

Say for example I am mapping one list to the next, and in the map I want to do some calculation with the current item in the list with the next item in the list.

```
def someFunc(L: List[Integer]) : List[Integer] = {
    L.collect {
        case k if (k != L(L.length-1)) //do something with k and the next element
    }
}
```

A simple example is I want to go through this List of Integers, and map each number onto the next number in the list divided by it.

E.g. (1,2,3) -> (2/1, 3/2) == (2, 1.5)

I had thought about doing this using indexOf but I don't think that is efficient having to search the whole list for the current element even though I am already traversing each element in the list anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.sliding` for this:

```
scala> val l = List(1, 2, 3)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> l.sliding(2).toList
res0: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2), List(2, 3))

scala> l.sliding(2).collect { case x::y::Nil if y != 0 => x / y.toDouble }.toList
res1: List[Double] = List(0.5, 0.6666666666666666)
```

Comment: You got the x and y in the wrong order, supposed to be `y/x`,  but the logic works. Thanks